# Is there a way to have git pre-push hooks on GitHub? Or Workarounds?

Tags: git, github, githooks

Goal:  I need to enforce a pre-push hook on my GitHub-hosted repository branches, which have collaborators, and unfortunately I can't find a way to get that hook to find its way into my collaborators' and my own .git/hooks directory.

I've spent time researching this issue and I've come across the following blockers:

- No GitHub server-side hooks so that's not an option. Not using GitHub Enterprise, we're using the hosted version.
- Cannot add .git/hooks/pre-push, because .git is an illegal directory to track.  GitHub of course won't let you create that directory, and if you try to add it locally git says that it's an invalid path.

Popular wisdom wants me to: push out the pre-push script in a different directory, and kindly ask my collaborates to symlink it.  No!  I need this to automatically populate.

I know myself better than git knows me.  How do I override the nanny protections so I can do what I need to do here?  Is there some magic with templates?

EDIT:  or any other creative solutions (services, integrations, webhooks, assuming they don't require setting up a server to talk back to!).

Comment: Why in the world would this get downvoted?  And questions like 'what is the difference between git pull and get fetch' get thousands of upvotes?

Comment: No idea, the questions seems just fine to me. If you really want an answer to that, you could try asking in [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do it with GitHub. As you have noticed, GitHub doesn't have server-side hooks, so that wont do. And for putting scripts in the repository that would automatically run for other users, well, that would be a HUGE security risk and it's obviously not possible to do with git.

You may try switching to another hosting solution that does allow server-side hooks, such as [GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/custom_hooks.html).

Comment: So far I'm just going to add the hook scripts to the repo, and a setup.sh which creates symlinks from the .git/hooks dir to the hook scripts in the repo.  I'll have people run the setup.sh.  However, I'd be far happier using something more automated, for example some of the service hooks that Github offers.  The annoying thing is they require you set up a server to talk back to.  

Unfortunately moving to Gitlab isn't a choice in this org.  But for future gigs, I most definitely will not recommend Github.